# INSERT INTO and primary keys, autoincrement fields, and default values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a PHP web app using a MySQL database.

I'm wondering what is the best way to find out what primary key (or any other autoincrement field) did a row receive after insertion.

Something that returns the full row as a result is also pretty good, since I also wanted to know about default values assigned to fields I didn't explicitly set.

All help is appreciated.

-- edit

So, I'm using an in-house framework that abstracts away the actual database functions, so I can't use the connection-specific "mysql_last_insert_id", and the "select last_insert_id" query, AFAIK, would be affected by other database connections, especially considering that the framework I'm using opens new connections for every query.

Guess this is a framework problem and you can't help me. If INSERT INTO had a "return inserted rows" mode, though, that would be nice.

Comment: -1: Zero research effort. This is well-documented on the page about `AUTO_INCREMENT` in the MySQL manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL provides a convenient way to answer this exact question:

```
mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

The `mysql_*` functions come with a wrapper for that: check [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

The mysql driver for PDO gives the same:

```
$pdo->exec('insert into ...');
$lastId = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: Found out how to do it using the framework we are using, but your answer is correct and complete if I were using MySQL or PDO directly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

**MySQL CODE:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `member` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

> SHOW:
> **AUTO_INCREMENT**

**MySQL Insert:**

```
INSERT INTO mytable (`id`,`name`,`update`,`created`) values (NULL,'TEST',NOW(),NOW());
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO mytable (`name`,`update`,`created`) values ('TEST',NOW(),NOW());
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO mytable (`name`,`created`) values ('TEST',NOW());
```

**PHP MySQL Code:**

```
<?php

$foo = 'test';

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (`name`,`created`) values ('".mysql_real_escape_string( $foo )."',NOW())");

// GET LAST ID
$id = mysql_insert_id();

?>
```

**In PHP use MYSQL_REAL_ESCAPE_STRING**

```
mysql_real_escape_string( string )
```

See this doc [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Bye!!

Comment: Everybody wins on this page but you helped me the most!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `mysql_*` functions, then you can simply use `mysql_insert_id()`. If you want the values of default rows, you'll have to select them using the key.